# Spring Data : native named query with LocalDate parameter

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I am using Spring Data with annotations.
I want to call a native named query with a parameter (LocalDate) through a repository.
When I call this query I am getting this error :

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1271, SQLState: HY000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'
c.g.r.event.EventBuilder$HostnameCache   : Updating the hostname cache
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1292, SQLState: 22007
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect date value: '��' for column 'entry_date' at row 1
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 1271, SQLState: HY000
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'
c.t.myApp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect      : Exception in com.techvalley.tecfel.web.rest.PlanningResource.getPays() with cause = {} and exception {}
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1274)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:780)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 175 common frames omitted
```

Here is my code, the date I put in param is correct ("2017-02-01"). :

Entity with named query:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Stock.getPlanningFromStock",
    query = "Select s.nom from stock where s.entry_date = :date1", resultSetMapping = "planningFromStockMapping" )
```

Spring MVC resource

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/stock-planning/{entryDate}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<PlanningDTO> getPlanning(@PathVariable @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate entryDate ) {


    List<PlanningDTO> plannings = stockRepository.getPlanningFromStock(entryDate);
    return null;
}
```

Repository :

```
List<PlanningDTO> getPlanningFromStock(@Param("date1") LocalDate date1);
```

Comment: What exact URL are you going for??

Comment: Actually, I formatted my localdate param as a string, and it works.